# valid parsed character XML data

Tags: xml, dtd

If I define an element such as this in a DTD

```
<!ELEMENT ud (#PCDATA)>
```

Are the following both valid?

```
<ud>foo &amp; bar</ud>
<ud><![CDATA[foo & bar]]></ud>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid.

Placing content in a `<![CDATA[]]>` section effectively means that whatever is in it will be ignored by the parser.

`PCDATA` means only character data is allowed. `CDATA` means, character data, so it is allowed within a `PCDATA` context.